# behaviors, где почитать

Tags: drupal, behaviors

Шестой друпал, чтоб его, использует невероятно древний джиквери, который не поддерживает лайв. - это условие. Увы, с этим ничего нельзя делать.

Есть два варианта: 
a) вставить ранний патч - livequery  
b) выучить behaviors(родная друпаловская вундервафля)

Вопрос: есть простой и понятный ресурс? Сайт друпала простым и понятным не считать.
Примеры простых и понятных сайтов: w3schools, jquery.com, php.net, php.su... итп.

В частности, интересует аналог live();
С меня плюсик и галочка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А посмотрите на этот [плагин](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery), может он будет работать с вашей версией jquery (А пробегаться снова и вешать событие не хотите)

Comment: я про лайвквери писал. В данном случае это скорее костыль. Это выход, но см. тему. Хочется поведение выучить